# Python парсинг через selenium, bs4

Tags: парсер, bs4

Появилась проблема с парсингом контента на этом [сайте](https://irinabot.ru) и в последующем добавление в список, к примеру ,при парсинге в `'NAME':item.find('td', class_='gamename').get_text(strip=True)` он может захватить вот этот тег: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Но мне нужно только название в class_='gamename'**

И еще одна проблема с парсингом `'PLAYERS':item.find('div', class_='ui horizontal list').get_text()` В нем нужно спарсить ники игроков, но он их в одну строку сливает без пробелов и запятых вот так: Post_147siuueya0N1Kto2tereshchuk_yuriNayton, но нужно чтобы было раздельно (Post_147,siuueya, 0N1Kto2 и т.д.). Уже пробовал спарсить отдельно class='item' в теге 'a' примерно вот так:

`'PLAYERS':item.find('a', class_='item').get_text()`

`'PLAYERS':item.find('div', class_='ui horizontal list')find('a').get_text()`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
for item in items:  
            try:
                self.game_list.append({     
                    'NAME':item.find('td', class_='gamename').get_text(strip=True),
                    'PLAYERS':item.find('div', class_='ui horizontal list').get_text() 
                    })
            except:
                break
                file.close()
```

Вот весь код:

```
import time
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

class Person:
    def get_data(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        # headless mode
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        #options.headless = True



        try:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
            driver.get('https://irinabot.ru')   
            time.sleep(1)
            with open("parse.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file: #Сохранение контента сайта
                file.write(driver.page_source)
                file.close()
            self.num = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="botstat"]/tr[1]/td[2]').text #Сохранение числа не начатых игр
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()


    def get_parse(self):
        #Открытие контента сайта
        with open('parse.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            f = file.read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")
        #Выделение каши 
        items = soup.find_all("tr", class_="gamebackgroud", limit=20)#int(self.num)) #Число не начатых игр которые нужно запарсить
        self.game_list = []




        #Добавление в список список игр
        for item in items:  
            try:
                self.game_list.append({     
                    'NAME':item.find('td', class_='gamename').get_text(strip=True), 
                    'PLAYERS':item.find('div', class_='ui horizontal list').get_text() 
                    })
            except:
                break
                file.close()
        print('.......Список игр.......\n',self.game_list, '\n........................')

    def search(self):
        #Поисковик игр
        flag = True

        for s in self.game_list:
            if re.search('zeml', str(s)):
                print('Игры под названием', s['NAME'])
                flag = False
            elif re.search('ZEML', str(s)):
                print('Игры под названием', s['NAME'])
                flag = False
            elif re.search('zemli', str(s)):
                print('Игры под названием', s['NAME'])
                flag = False
            elif re.search('Zemli', str(s)):
                print('Игры под названием', s['NAME'])
                flag = False
            elif re.search('земли', str(s)):
                print('Игры под названием', s['NAME'])
                flag = False
            elif re.search('ZeM', str(s)):
                print('Игры под названием', s['NAME'])
                flag = False
        if flag:
            print('Игра не найдена')


p = Person()
p.get_data()
p.get_parse()
p.search()
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с разделением тегов запятой в списке PLAYERS следующим образом:
`'PLAYERS':item.find('div', class_='ui horizontal list').get_text(',')`